# How to plot the Curve fitting with Bayesian Ridge Regression using specific dataset columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting, bayesian, polynomials

In order to plot the Bayesian regression I am following the method found at:
"https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_bayesian_ridge_curvefit.html"

I cannot match my x,y plot axis data to my columns, then pass it to the `def Func(x)`
which should generate the plot functions of the plot. The output terminal throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/...../......./....py", line 26, in <module>
    y_train = func(x_train) + ['Low'] ##.(scale=0.1, size=size)
  File "/home/....../....../......py", line 10, in func
    def func(x): return (np.sin(2*np.pi*x))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

In the code shown I am attempting to use data from column/tables in order to plot the Fitted Bayesian Regression; whereas the "scikit" example is using random generated numbers, I didn't think it would be much of an issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt


def func(x): return (np.sin(2*np.pi*x))


rng = pdr.get_data_yahoo('GM', start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2016')

# Reset Index And Convert Dates Into Numerical Format
rng['Ticks'] = range(0,len(rng.index.values))
rng = rng.reset_index()
# Restructure Data Into OHLC Format
rng = rng[['High', 'Low', 'Ticks']]
print(rng.head(25))
# #############################################################################
# Generate sinusoidal data with noise
size = 25
rng = rng[['High', 'Low', 'Ticks']]
x_train = ['Ticks']##(0., 1., size) ##rng.uniform(0., 1., size)
y_train = func(x_train) + ['Low'] ##.(scale=0.1, size=size)
x_test = np.linspace(0., 1., 100)


# #############################################################################
# Fit by cubic polynomial
n_order = 3
X_train = np.vander(x_train, n_order + 1, increasing=True)
X_test = np.vander(x_test, n_order + 1, increasing=True)

# #############################################################################
# Plot the true and predicted curves with log marginal likelihood (L)
reg = BayesianRidge(tol=1e-6, fit_intercept=False, compute_score=True)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    # Bayesian ridge regression with different initial value pairs
    if i == 0:
        init = [1 / np.var(y_train), 1.]  # Default values
    elif i == 1:
        init = [1., 1e-3]
        reg.set_params(alpha_init=init[0], lambda_init=init[1])
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ymean, ystd = reg.predict(X_test, return_std=True)

    ax.plot(x_test, func(x_test), color="blue", label="sin($2\\pi x$)")
    ax.scatter(x_train, y_train, s=50, alpha=0.5, label="observation")
    ax.plot(x_test, ymean, color="red", label="predict mean")
    ax.fill_between(x_test, ymean-ystd, ymean+ystd,
                    color="pink", alpha=0.5, label="predict std")
    ax.set_ylim(-1.3, 1.3)
    ax.legend()
    title = "$\\alpha$_init$={:.2f},\\ \\lambda$_init$={}$".format(
            init[0], init[1])
    if i == 0:
        title += " (Default)"
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=12)
    text = "$\\alpha={:.1f}$\n$\\lambda={:.3f}$\n$L={:.1f}$".format(
           reg.alpha_, reg.lambda_, reg.scores_[-1])
    ax.text(0.05, -1.0, text, fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `x_train = rng['Ticks'] `and `y_train = func(x_train) + rng['Low']`If you modify the graph in this way, the graph will output You just couldn't get the data.

Comment: Making the changes mentioned above, has returned this traceback.```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/inmachine/Python Progs/Bayesian2.py", line 26, in <module>
    y_train = func(x_train) + rng['Low'] ##.(scale=0.1, size=size)
  File "/home/inmachine/Python Progs/Bayesian2.py", line 10, in func
    def func(x): return (np.sin(2*np.pi*x))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' ```

Comment: The error we could see when debugging is `x_train=['Ticks']`. This is assigning a list. I modified this to the code I returned in the comments and the graph was created. Shall I post the answer once, though I can delete it later?

Comment: It would be highly appreciated; and most helpful, as I made the changes but it threw the traceback. Python 3.XXXX. I shall be looking out for the post

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
from sklearn.linear_model import BayesianRidge
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

def func(x): return (np.sin(2*np.pi*x))

rng = pdr.get_data_yahoo('GM', start='3/14/2009', end='4/14/2016')

# Reset Index And Convert Dates Into Numerical Format
rng['Ticks'] = range(0,len(rng.index.values))
rng = rng.reset_index()
# Restructure Data Into OHLC Format
rng = rng[['High', 'Low', 'Ticks']]
# print(rng.head(25))
# #############################################################################
# Generate sinusoidal data with noise
size = 25
rng = rng[['High', 'Low', 'Ticks']]
x_train = rng['Ticks']##(0., 1., size) ##rng.uniform(0., 1., size)
y_train = func(x_train) + rng['Low'] ##.(scale=0.1, size=size)
x_test = np.linspace(min(x_train), max(x_train), 100)


# #############################################################################
# Fit by cubic polynomial
n_order = 3
X_train = np.vander(x_train, n_order + 1, increasing=True)
X_test = np.vander(x_test, n_order + 1, increasing=True)

# #############################################################################
# Plot the true and predicted curves with log marginal likelihood (L)
reg = BayesianRidge(tol=1e-6, fit_intercept=False, compute_score=True)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))
for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
    # Bayesian ridge regression with different initial value pairs
    if i == 0:
        init = [1 / np.var(y_train), 1.]  # Default values
    elif i == 1:
        init = [1., 1e-3]
        reg.set_params(alpha_init=init[0], lambda_init=init[1])
    reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
    ymean, ystd = reg.predict(X_test, return_std=True)

    ax.plot(x_test, func(x_test), color="blue", label="sin($2\\pi x$)")
    ax.scatter(x_train, y_train, s=50, alpha=0.5, label="observation")
    ax.plot(x_test, ymean, color="red", label="predict mean")
    ax.fill_between(x_test, ymean-ystd, ymean+ystd,
                    color="pink", alpha=0.5, label="predict std")
    ax.set_ylim(-50, 50)
    ax.legend()
    title = "$\\alpha$_init$={:.2f},\\ \\lambda$_init$={}$".format(
            init[0], init[1])
    if i == 0:
        title += " (Default)"
    ax.set_title(title, fontsize=12)
    text = "$\\alpha={:.1f}$\n$\\lambda={:.3f}$\n$L={:.1f}$".format(
           reg.alpha_, reg.lambda_, reg.scores_[-1])
    ax.text(0.05, -1.0, text, fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The size of your data is different from the data indicated in the comments. For example, if you modify it to `ax.set_ylim(-50, 50)`, the scatterplot will be displayed, but you should check the range of the y-axis again.

Comment: `x_test = np.linspace(min(x_train), max(x_train), 100)`The x-axis also needs to be corrected and the code and graphs updated.

Comment: Plotly's candlesticks would be a good reference for [this](https://plotly.com/python/candlestick-charts/); I'm not sure about the 3D.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bayesian regression, but there is an official sample in the [AI category](https://plotly.com/python/ai-ml/). Good luck!

Comment: +1..+1 For your time and help. What can you suggest, in order to get x_test/ blue line at 0, to fall in line with the plot.

Comment: ax.set_ylim(.., ..) , May work better if the highest value and lowest value within the date range is returned/ passed to it. This may also be used to solve x_test position (being stuck at 0). Just; don't know how to correctly code it....